# How can I access properties of an object in js which starts with particular pattern?

Tags: javascript

How can I access properties of an object in js which starts with particular pattern?

```
 Object object {
  s_id: 'sscdsdcksd',
  name: 'xyz',
  attachment_fdept: 'x.pdf',
  attachment_xdept: 'y.pdf'
 }
```

Now I want to access all the properties of an object starting with attachment. How can I do this?

Comment: That isn't valid JavaScript...

Comment: Iterate through object.keys, checking the pattern against each

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var myObject = {
  s_id: 'sscdsdcksd',
  name: 'xyz',
  attachment_fdept: 'x.pdf',
  attachment_xdept: 'y.pdf'
};
for (var key in myObject) {
  if (myObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    /*
     Define your pattern here. 
     You can use regex for a more complicated pattern
     */
    if (key.indexOf("attachment") === 0) {
      console.log(key + " : " + myObject[key]);
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: `key.indexOf("attachment") > - 1` that searchs if the key _contains_ `attachment` not if it _starts with_ the word. A key called `not_attachment` will also be matched.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out : ) A very detailed reading! However the key thing here is to be able to specify you own pattern in the if clause

Answer (score 2):

You can get the keys with `Object.keys()` and filter them with `.filter()`:

```
Object.keys(obj).filter( key => key.startsWith('attachment') )
```

```js
var obj = {
  s_id: 'sscdsdcksd',
  name: 'xyz',
  attachment_fdept: 'x.pdf',
  attachment_xdept: 'y.pdf'
}

var keys = Object.keys(obj).filter( key => key.startsWith('attachment') )

console.log(keys);
```

If you also need the values, not only the property names, then:

```
Object.keys(obj).filter( key => key.startsWith('attachment') )
                .map ( key => [key, obj[key]] );
```

```js
var obj = {
  s_id: 'sscdsdcksd',
  name: 'xyz',
  attachment_fdept: 'x.pdf',
  attachment_xdept: 'y.pdf'
}

var pairs = Object.keys(obj).filter( key => key.startsWith('attachment') )
                            .map ( key => [key, obj[key]] );

console.log(pairs);
```

Comment: `key.indexOf('attachment')` - that returns `0` which is falsey for the first parameter. Instead of converting this to a boolean using NOT, I find it way more readable if it's an explicit check `key.indexOf('attachment') == 0`

Comment: Better yet use `startsWith`